# How to change Wordpress site block quotes to pull quotes

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress site has annoying way to convert your pull quotes["] to block quotes[“]. If you run your wordpress site to store your sql queries or developer stuff like that, it is annoying as you cannot directly run/use them by copy pasting from your wordpress site. If you also face the same issue please follow my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you also face this issue edit the current theme functions.php and added below codes to the end of the file.

```
<?php
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');remove_filter('the_title', 'wptexturize');remove_filter('comment_text', 'wptexturize');
?>
```